# Difference between ref_block_num and ref_block_prefix and how to retrieve it?

Tags: transactions, block-header

I am trying to construct a header of a transaction. 
So my question is - what is the difference between ref_block_num and ref_block_prefix in a transaction header and how to retrieve it? 
is there a way to get these information from `v1/chain/get_info` ?

Many thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  ref_block_num     ///< specifies a block num in the last 2^16 blocks.
  ref_block_prefix  ///< specifies the lower 32 bits of the blockid at get_ref_blocknum

  ...

  /**
  * @return the absolute block number given the relative ref_block_num
  */
  block_num_type get_ref_blocknum( block_num_type head_blocknum )const {
     return ((head_blocknum/0xffff)*0xffff) + head_blocknum%0xffff;
  }
```

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/e87d245da0e458edc66139c3ca59f71861bcc1dd/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/transaction.hpp#L32

---

Dan elaborates | [Source](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/102/can-someone-explain-the-transaction-struct).:

> **ref_block_num** / **ref_block_prefix** -> this transaction can only in
>   blockchains where **the highest** block_num%0xff has a blockid that
>   contains ref_block_prefix. Stated another way, this says the
>   transaction can only be included in forks that build off of the
>   reference block.
>
> Taken together the transaction is only valid for the specified period
>   of time and can be declared invalid if it isn't included in a block by
>   the time the last irreversible block time is equal to the expiration.
>
> EOSIO uses this information to prevent replay attacks on transactions.

---

[From docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#push_transactions)

> The **ref_block_num** and **ref_block_prefix** here are provided as a result
>   of **/v1/chain/get_block** of the last_irreversible_block. The
>   last_irreversible_block can be found by calling /v1/chain/get_info.
>   You also need to use /v1/wallet/sign_transaction to get the right
>   signature.

```
REQUEST:
---------------------
POST /v1/chain/get_info HTTP/1.0
Host: jungle2.cryptolions.io
content-length: 0
Accept: */*
Connection: close


---------------------
RESPONSE:
---------------------
{
  "server_version": "ea08cfd3",
  "chain_id": "e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473",
  "head_block_num": 3324665,
  This guy
  "last_irreversible_block_num": 3324336,
  Right there ^
  "last_irreversible_block_id": "0032b9b007cf91079677cb22a523fce2402ed92334958f64a124222cb8b06ecc",
  "head_block_id": "0032baf9d0d72cfa104884c8cd5ca031a3c65d8ff7e373052b3f0c967375c6c3",
  "head_block_time": "2018-12-13T03:19:50.000",
  "head_block_producer": "jungleswedem",
  "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 200000000,
  "virtual_block_net_limit": 1048576000,
  "block_cpu_limit": 199920,
  "block_net_limit": 1048576,
  "server_version_string": "v1.5.0"
}
```

cleos get block 1:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-03-02T12:00:00.000",
  "producer": "",
  "confirmed": 1,
  "previous": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "transaction_mroot": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "action_mroot": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "schedule_version": 0,
  "new_producers": null,
  "header_extensions": [],
  "producer_signature": "SIG_K1_111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111116uk5ne",
  "transactions": [],
  "block_extensions": [],
  "id": "0000000130d70e94e0022fd2fa035cabb9e542c34ea27f572ac90b5a7aa3d891",
  "block_num": 1,
  Other guy
  "ref_block_prefix": 3526296288
  Is right here ^, this took a long time to put together
}
```

---

Full transaction.

- req `POST /v1/chain/get_info HTTP/1.0`
- req `POST /v1/wallet/get_public_keys HTTP/1.0`
- req `POST /v1/chain/get_required_keys HTTP/1.0` (***get ref_block_num & ref_block_prefix here)***
- req `POST /v1/wallet/sign_transaction HTTP/1.0`
- req `POST /v1/chain/push_transaction HTTP/1.0`

---

```
REQUEST:

POST /v1/chain/get_info HTTP/1.0
Host: jungle2.cryptolions.io
content-length: 0
Accept: */*
Connection: close



RESPONSE:

{
  "server_version": "ea08cfd3",
  "chain_id": "e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473",
  "head_block_num": 3324665,
  "last_irreversible_block_num": 3324336,
  "last_irreversible_block_id": "0032b9b007cf91079677cb22a523fce2402ed92334958f64a124222cb8b06ecc",
  "head_block_id": "0032baf9d0d72cfa104884c8cd5ca031a3c65d8ff7e373052b3f0c967375c6c3",
  "head_block_time": "2018-12-13T03:19:50.000",
  "head_block_producer": "jungleswedem",
  "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 200000000,
  "virtual_block_net_limit": 1048576000,
  "block_cpu_limit": 199920,
  "block_net_limit": 1048576,
  "server_version_string": "v1.5.0"
}

REQUEST:

POST /v1/wallet/get_public_keys HTTP/1.0
Host: /home/natanaelprudhomme/eosio-wallet/keosd.sock:
content-length: 0
Accept: */*
Connection: close



RESPONSE:

[
  "EOS5QaqpbQtA98cBbYwhK49wdm2Qdhf7x4hYHb9WkvrSLUNxWm995",
  "EOS5WgXLzLwTXKeRGQV3BSn1saGtT4bkA8jbfLc4L1uTPb9sN6UAw",
  "EOS63zNBrWgKWp2P9pqL5vvKWRdUtJX9tznamw8MkxVSeMGgWYVD5",
  "EOS67wLi78ak2fqffpvGedNqRTEcEeNTZhKBxM3n3cgjBwGerEZgv",
  "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV",
  "EOS7dsJbPAhRCjTwPB28nithDunNZ1oCMTNRC8g31Y3oahx3w62z8",
  "EOS7jEjKydV7Ve7KbkLNbC6WYpTEqCy7KU8asuWJNu1e3qsGYmic2",
  "EOS85wQgYFL2GnU368P3PVDShMpcqcXTVd1JpLBNTMt5jMEBUBUhv",
  "EOS8DEzBSBrYTJu5GdnsN5oJm5QHPT4zqgLGcPuZuc8Xgfib31Xux"
]

REQUEST:

POST /v1/chain/get_required_keys HTTP/1.0
Host: jungle2.cryptolions.io
content-length: 1213
Accept: */*
Connection: close

{
  "transaction": {
    "expiration": "2018-12-13T03:20:20",
    "ref_block_num": 47536,
    "ref_block_prefix": 583759766,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
        "account": "eosio",
        "name": "updateauth",
        "authorization": [{
            "actor": "eosezchatnat",
            "permission": "owner"
          }
        ],
        "data": "90cdcca6a1af305500000000a8ed32320000000080ab26a7010000000100039205fa96bd143deddb53d53e810d7e5292ddeb592a9633c64d963d68dbbc72e201000000"
      }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": []
  },
  "available_keys": [
    "EOS5QaqpbQtA98cBbYwhK49wdm2Qdhf7x4hYHb9WkvrSLUNxWm995",
    "EOS5WgXLzLwTXKeRGQV3BSn1saGtT4bkA8jbfLc4L1uTPb9sN6UAw",
    "EOS63zNBrWgKWp2P9pqL5vvKWRdUtJX9tznamw8MkxVSeMGgWYVD5",
    "EOS67wLi78ak2fqffpvGedNqRTEcEeNTZhKBxM3n3cgjBwGerEZgv",
    "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV",
    "EOS7dsJbPAhRCjTwPB28nithDunNZ1oCMTNRC8g31Y3oahx3w62z8",
    "EOS7jEjKydV7Ve7KbkLNbC6WYpTEqCy7KU8asuWJNu1e3qsGYmic2",
    "EOS85wQgYFL2GnU368P3PVDShMpcqcXTVd1JpLBNTMt5jMEBUBUhv",
    "EOS8DEzBSBrYTJu5GdnsN5oJm5QHPT4zqgLGcPuZuc8Xgfib31Xux"
  ]
}

RESPONSE:

{
  "required_keys": [
    "EOS5QaqpbQtA98cBbYwhK49wdm2Qdhf7x4hYHb9WkvrSLUNxWm995"
  ]
}

REQUEST:

POST /v1/wallet/sign_transaction HTTP/1.0
Host: /home/natanaelprudhomme/eosio-wallet/keosd.sock:
content-length: 807
Accept: */*
Connection: close

[{
    "expiration": "2018-12-13T03:20:20",
    "ref_block_num": 47536,
    "ref_block_prefix": 583759766,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
        "account": "eosio",
        "name": "updateauth",
        "authorization": [{
            "actor": "eosezchatnat",
            "permission": "owner"
          }
        ],
        "data": "90cdcca6a1af305500000000a8ed32320000000080ab26a7010000000100039205fa96bd143deddb53d53e810d7e5292ddeb592a9633c64d963d68dbbc72e201000000"
      }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
  },[
    "EOS5QaqpbQtA98cBbYwhK49wdm2Qdhf7x4hYHb9WkvrSLUNxWm995"
  ],
  "e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473"
]

RESPONSE:

{
  "expiration": "2018-12-13T03:20:20",
  "ref_block_num": 47536,
  "ref_block_prefix": 583759766,
  "max_net_usage_words": 0,
  "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
  "delay_sec": 0,
  "context_free_actions": [],
  "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio",
      "name": "updateauth",
      "authorization": [{
          "actor": "eosezchatnat",
          "permission": "owner"
        }
      ],
      "data": "90cdcca6a1af305500000000a8ed32320000000080ab26a7010000000100039205fa96bd143deddb53d53e810d7e5292ddeb592a9633c64d963d68dbbc72e201000000"
    }
  ],
  "transaction_extensions": [],
  "signatures": [
    "SIG_K1_KA3jZ6oTMeUUHnpAsXCh9Z6JLHhQavgp9k1pK8W8o6nAmTcJUipPYSP1Fm64WWsw6jn1UcwBSmCoXfkWuPsqqos6DP3AbD"
  ],
  "context_free_data": []
}

REQUEST:

POST /v1/chain/push_transaction HTTP/1.0
Host: jungle2.cryptolions.io
content-length: 446
Accept: */*
Connection: close

{
  "signatures": [
    "SIG_K1_KA3jZ6oTMeUUHnpAsXCh9Z6JLHhQavgp9k1pK8W8o6nAmTcJUipPYSP1Fm64WWsw6jn1UcwBSmCoXfkWuPsqqos6DP3AbD"
  ],
  "compression": "none",
  "packed_context_free_data": "",
  "packed_trx": "f4cf115cb0b99677cb2200000000010000000000ea30550040cbdaa86c52d50190cdcca6a1af30550000000080ab26a74390cdcca6a1af305500000000a8ed32320000000080ab26a7010000000100039205fa96bd143deddb53d53e810d7e5292ddeb592a9633c64d963d68dbbc72e20100000000"
}

RESPONSE:

{
  "transaction_id": "3e7a7805c17e0621822c63dc2a90f59713acd1ee2a8b4390385183375d3617f0",
  "processed": {
    "id": "3e7a7805c17e0621822c63dc2a90f59713acd1ee2a8b4390385183375d3617f0",
    "block_num": 3324669,
    "block_time": "2018-12-13T03:19:52.000",
    "producer_block_id": null,
    "receipt": {
      "status": "executed",
      "cpu_usage_us": 512,
      "net_usage_words": 20
    },
    "elapsed": 512,
    "net_usage": 160,
    "scheduled": false,
    "action_traces": [{
        "receipt": {
          "receiver": "eosio",
          "act_digest": "5d7da6b5aff4f83a95c691965507d34b05c79723bf8d3cb84b918a1a89404039",
          "global_sequence": 21018317,
          "recv_sequence": 4666459,
          "auth_sequence": [[
              "eosezchatnat",
              294
            ]
          ],
          "code_sequence": 2,
          "abi_sequence": 3
        },
        "act": {
          "account": "eosio",
          "name": "updateauth",
          "authorization": [{
              "actor": "eosezchatnat",
              "permission": "owner"
            }
          ],
          "data": {
            "account": "eosezchatnat",
            "permission": "active",
            "parent": "owner",
            "auth": {
              "threshold": 1,
              "keys": [{
                  "key": "EOS7wYVzWFWFu8AViGr8XZvb3npfPz9btujCLQ5d7PZtsbHeorgw3",
                  "weight": 1
                }
              ],
              "accounts": [],
              "waits": []
            }
          },
          "hex_data": "90cdcca6a1af305500000000a8ed32320000000080ab26a7010000000100039205fa96bd143deddb53d53e810d7e5292ddeb592a9633c64d963d68dbbc72e201000000"
        },
        "context_free": false,
        "elapsed": 87,
        "console": "",
        "trx_id": "3e7a7805c17e0621822c63dc2a90f59713acd1ee2a8b4390385183375d3617f0",
        "block_num": 3324669,
        "block_time": "2018-12-13T03:19:52.000",
        "producer_block_id": null,
        "account_ram_deltas": [{
            "account": "eosezchatnat",
            "delta": 0
          }
        ],
        "except": null,
        "inline_traces": []
      }
    ],
    "except": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate! This was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Very glad to hear that.  Took me a hot minute to put that guy together.